# copy and replace multiple folders, into user’s “My Documents \My Data” into corresponding folders that have the same name as the folders to be copied

Tags: batch-file, copy

Windows 7- batch script help, please:
I need to modify the script below to copy and paste/overwrite multiple folders, (not move files) from the server to each user’s “My Documents \My Data” into corresponding folders that have the same name as the folders to be copied.
I did some research and found Klint’s response at: http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/copy-files-to-folders-with-samename/18511.html

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "C:\Change to\Whateveryour\path"
for %%j in (*) do (
set name=%%~nj
if exist !name!\ (
move "%%j" "!name!"
) else (
echo Warning: %%j not moved to !name!: folder does not exist.
)
)
popd
pause
exit
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set destination="some_folder\"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "C:\Change to\Whateveryour\path"
for /D %%j in (".\*") do (
  set f_name=%%j
  if exist !name!\ (
    xcopy "%%j" "!destination!\%%~nj" /I /S /Y /C /H /R
  ) else (
    echo Warning: %%j not moved to !name!: folder does not exist.
  )
)
popd
pause
exit
```

For directory iteration `FOR /F` id more convenient.To copy a folder structure you need `XCOPY` or `ROBOCOPY` (here I used `XCOPY`).Move works only with files.

Comment: thanks npocmaka for your assistance, but i get " invalid number of parameters:(

Comment: most probably this comes from `xcpoy`.Try with `xcopy "%%j" "!destination!\%%~nj" /I /S /Y` ...